# Python SQLite3 difference between [] and ()

Tags: python, sqlite

I was reading some SQLite documentation and don't really understand the difference between using [brackets] and using (parentheses).

`c.execute('INSERT INTO list VALUES(?)', [name])`

`c.execute('INSERT INTO list VALUES(?)', (name))`

`c.execute('INSERT INTO list VALUES(?, ?)', ('name', 'age')`

Could something like this work?

`c.execute('INSERT INTO list VALUES(?, ?)', [name, age])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that works too. The difference between them:

- [brackets] are [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) <sup>(or [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))</sup>
- (parentheses) are [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) <sup>(or [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions))</sup>

The `parameters` parameter for [cur.execute()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) expects:

- an iterable or *sequence* of values to put into the query placeholders, using question mark placeholders - lists, tuples. This is what you're using above.
- or, named placeholders which map param names to their values - a dictionary.

You can use either in your query. Side effects are minimal but tuples are preferred since they are immutable and have fewer methods. So Python needs less resources to create and use them. This is true for most methods/functions that expect a sequence.

```
>>> # This is the qmark style:
>>> cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", (who, age))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002C2E3B0>
>>>
>>> # *** this is also qmark style, but with a list of params instead of a tuple of params ***
>>> cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", [who, age])
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002C2E3B0>
>>>
>>> cur.execute('select * from people')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002C2E3B0>
>>> cur.fetchall()
[('Yeltsin', 72), ('Yeltsin', 72)]
>>>
```

---

A note on `c.execute('INSERT INTO list VALUES(?)', (name))`, from [bereal's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59799678/python-sqlite3-difference-between-and/59800468#comment105741627_59800468):

`[name]` is a list with one element. If you want to create a *tuple* with one element, you need to add a comma to express that: `(name,)`. Otherwise, `(name)` is just `name` and in the query. That's a string, which itself is an iterable and would expand to a sequence of each character in the string.

```
>>> list('Yeltsin')
['Y', 'e', 'l', 't', 's', 'i', 'n']
>>> tuple('Yeltsin')
('Y', 'e', 'l', 't', 's', 'i', 'n')
```

So if you `execute()`'ed that, it treats the string as a sequence complains that you've passed in too many parameters:

```
>>> cur.execute("insert into people values (?)", (who))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.
```

The correct way with a tuple for just one paramater:

```
>>> cur.execute("insert into people values (?)", (who,))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002698A40>
>>>
>>> # or with a list, no comma needed
>>> cur.execute("insert into people values (?)", [who])
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002698A40>
>>>
```

Comment: I'd add to this, that `(name)` in the question is not a tuple, and won't work like `[name]`. `(name)` is exactly the same as `name`, and has to be `(name,)` if one wants a tuple.